# Upload blobs to server side disk using Java Spring, which are sent using XMLHttpRequest Formdata

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest, blob

My form is sending a video and audio blobs as a POST request using XMLHttpRequest

At server side Spring controller -- I would like to retrieve the HTTP request and pass those two blobs and save it to hard disk as two files.

Can someone help me on this. Thanks!

here's my JS code

```
 function sendAudioVideoBlobs(){

    console.log("Sending blobs!");
    var recordForm = new FormData();

    recordForm.append("video", videoBlob);
    recordForm.append("audio", audioBlob);

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    formSubmitURL = "http://localhost:8088/openmrs/module/patientnarratives/webRtcMedia.form";
    console.log(formSubmitURL);

    oReq.open("POST", formSubmitURL);
    oReq.send(recordForm);

}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class WebRtcMediaStreamController {

private String returnUrl;
public final static String FORM_PATH = "/module/patientnarratives/webRtcMedia.form";
protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

private String audioUrl = "/home/audioFile1.wav";
private String videoUrl = "/home/videoFile1.webm";

@RequestMapping(FORM_PATH)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    Integer encId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("textEncID"));

    if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
        MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        MultipartFile videofile             = (MultipartFile) multipartRequest.getFile("video");
        MultipartFile audiofile             = (MultipartFile) multipartRequest.getFile("audio");

        byte[] videoData = videofile.getBytes();
        byte[] audioData = audiofile.getBytes();

        if (!videofile.isEmpty()) {
            if (videofile.getSize() > 0) {  // limit video length or size.

                OutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(new File(videoUrl));
                out1.write(videoData);
                out1.close();

                OutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(new File(audioUrl));
                out2.write(audioData);
                out2.close();
            }
        }
    }

    returnUrl = request.getContextPath() + "/module/patientnarratives/patientNarrativesForm.form";
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(returnUrl));
}
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? Does this code not work? Also spring has annotations for dealing with file/binary uploads